# I'm having problems with the project building on Read the Docs

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Created sphinx project with sphinx-quickstart.  Ran "make html" and no errors produced.  Pushed all the code to GitHub.  I tried to import and build project on Read the Docs, but get the following errors.  I haven't problems when using a Mac- it builds and renders the code on Read the Docs.  This time I'm using Windows 10.

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/thirddocs/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 304, in build_main
    app.build(args.force_all, filenames)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/thirddocs/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 341, in build
    self.builder.build_update()
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/thirddocs/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 347, in build_update
    len(to_build))
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/thirddocs/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 360, in build
    updated_docnames = set(self.read())
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/thirddocs/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 472, in read
    self.env.doc2path(self.config.master_doc))
sphinx.errors.SphinxError: master file /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/thirddocs/checkouts/latest/contents.rst not found

Sphinx error:
master file /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/thirddocs/checkouts/latest/contents.rst not found
```

Comment: You need to tell RTD to install your project. See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#my-project-isn-t-building-with-autodoc

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's downloading everything it needs to with sphinx-quickstart.  Like it doesn't ask me as many questions when I'm installing as it does when I'm using it on a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked by just adding master_doc = 'index' to the conf.py file.

Comment: Since Sphinx 2.0, `index` is the default value: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-master_doc